# Cache headers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I`m trying to add cache headers on my static files (.css, .js), but only way I found is with some .htaccess stuff that make the page to throw 500 error. So my question is whether there is easier way to add those headers?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this short post that explains exactly how to do it. I have it bookmarked and always refer to it when do starting with caching.

http://derekdevries.com/2007/12/13/rails-asset-cache/

Comment: sorry about that, link added to answer

Comment: well the answer is 2.5 years old but I'll try find an updated link

Comment: I have found a new link for you and its in the updated answer

Comment: Another great resource for caching in rails are the Newrelic scaling screencasts by Gregg Pollack. http://railslab.newrelic.com/scaling-rails